# Dynamically Allocated 2D-Array not initializing

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-arrays

This code is supposed to allocate, initialize and print a 2-D array. For some reason depending on the value of N the 4th column has different values. (Everything should be 0).

```
int N = 10; 
int **A;   
int i, j;
A = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    A[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Sample Output:

```
0 0 0 0 12 0 0 
0 0 0 0 10 0 0 
0 0 0 0 8 0 0 
0 0 0 0 6 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;
```

should be

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  for (j=0;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][j]=0;
```

The value of `i` and `j` should start from `0` and also `A[i][i]` should be `A[i][j]`

Answer (score 3):

Where you wrote

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;
```

use

```
A[i][j]=0;
```

or you'll only initialize the diagonal. Better yet: Use `calloc` to allocate the arrays:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  A[i] = calloc(N, sizeof(int));
```

then the memory will come zero-initialized, and you'll not have to do anything anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You are only initializing the diagonal of the "matrix", except for `A[0][0]`, which remains uninitialized because you start looping at index `1`:

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;
```

You need

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  for (j=0;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][j]=0;
```

or use `memset` to set all the values in the inner arrays to `0`.

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  memset(A[i], 0, N*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;
```

Will initialize only the 1 - Nth element of A[i]. `A[i][j]=0;` is what you want here.

Also consider using memset to initialize that array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   memset(A[i], 0, N * 4); // sizeof(int) = 4
```

Comment: `A[i]` is an `int*`, so `sizeof(A[i])` won't work very well here.

Comment: whoops I oversaw that. Expected it to be an int[]. I'll edit it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bug in the code:

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][i]=0;
```

should be

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++)
  for (j=1;j<N;j++) 
    A[i][j]=0;
```